# May I delete all the files created by HPLIP installer after successful installation?

Tags: hplip

I successfully installed my HP M1132 MFP printer by running `hplip-3.15.11.run` script. On Mint 17.3 Beta and Debian 8.2. The printer, including scan, works. What's more, I didn't get into any kind of trouble while installing it. Seamless.

There is just one thing. It didn't tell me in the end, if I may delete those 3548 files created inside the folder, where I ran it, while installation. So, I my question is - may I? Did it install locally into the folder or into the system?

Comment: why install it with `hplip-3.15.11.run` when hplip is packaged for debian?  `apt-cache search -n hplip`.  is there really such an important difference between 3.15.11 and 3.14.6-1+b3?

Comment: @cas It is also pre-packed in Mint. However, this printer requires proprietary plugin. The download of the plugin failed on both systems with the pre-packed version. It may have been my fault, I am unsure. I only wanted it to work. I would not care about the latest version of HPLIP otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to check would be to rename the directory and test scanning and printing. If it does (or doesn't work), you'll have your answer.

As another option you can always check if the binaries are install to /bin /opt/[some directory].

Answer (score 0):

YES, according to https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/193620 and also based on my own experience on Ubuntu 16.04.